# Probabilistic matchmaking simulation

Tags: c++, c++11, random, simulation, numerical-methods

The following is a problem I found on this [wiki](http://wiki.quantsoftware.org/index.php?title=Compinvesti-prog-quiz). What can I do to optimize my algorithm, and make this code more C++11?

> Write a program to discover the answer to this puzzle:"Let's say men
>   and women are paid equally (from the same uniform distribution). If
>   women date randomly and marry the first man with a higher salary, what
>   fraction of the population will get married?"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
//#include <cstdlib>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::random_shuffle;


const int MIN = 1;
const int MAX = 1000000;
const int MALES = 100;
const int FEMALES = 100;

class Female{
public:
    Female(){isMarried = false;}

    bool isMarried;
    int salary;
};

class Male{
public:
    Male(){isMarried = false;}

    bool isMarried;
    int salary;
};

void marriageTest(std::vector<double> &results){

    double count = 0;
    bool done = false;

    Male male[MALES];
    Female female[FEMALES];

    //Fill array of Females and Males with random salaries ranging from 1 to 10
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        int output = MIN + (rand() % (int)(MAX - MIN + 1));
        i[male].salary = output; //( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
    }
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        int output = MIN + (rand() % (int)(MAX - MIN + 1));
        i[female].salary = output;
    }


    //Start dating
    //Keep dating until the maximum salary of males is lower than minimum salary of females

    do{
        random_shuffle(&male[0], &male[MALES]);               //Shuffle array of males
        random_shuffle(&female[0], &female[FEMALES]);           //Shuffle array of females


        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){                              //Compare a female and male from both arrays
            if(female[i].salary < male[i].salary)
                if(!female[i].isMarried && !male[i].isMarried){
                    count++;
                    female[i].isMarried = true;
                    male[i].isMarried = true;
                }
        }

        //Check for Maximum Male Salary
        int maxMen = MIN;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            if(male[i].salary > maxMen && !male[i].isMarried)
                maxMen = male[i].salary;
        }

        //Check for Minimum Female Salary
        int minWomen = MAX;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            if(female[i].salary < minWomen && !female[i].isMarried)
                minWomen = female[i].salary;
        }

        if(maxMen <= minWomen)
            done = true;


    }while(!done);

    results.push_back(count/100);
}

void runTrials(int num_trials, std::vector<double> &results){

    for(int i=0; i<num_trials;i++)
        marriageTest(results);
}

double Percentage(std::vector<double> &results){

    double final = 0;
    int trials = 0;
    for(auto i : results){
        final += i;
        ++trials;
    }

    return final/trials;
}


int main()
{
    int num_trials;
    std::vector<double> results;

    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << "Number of trials: ";
    cin >> num_trials;

    runTrials(num_trials,results);

    double final = Percentage(results);

    cout << "Percentage: " << final << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are there limits on the number of people male/female can marry?

Comment: Assuming there is an (identical) finite number of men and women, or an infinite supply thereof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several changes you can apply to add more C++11 features and practices to your code. To name a few:

1. Use [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) for constants.
2. Use [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) instead of `std::random_shuffle`. 
   The `random_shuffle` overload that uses a default RNG is considered deprecated.
3. Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of C arrays (for `male[]` and `female[]`).
4. Use the new [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) library instead of `std::rand()`.
5. Don't use C-style casts: `(int)(MAX - MIN + 1)`. [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) is the correct in way here.

Other things:

1. Initialize data in constructors the proper way: `Female() : isMarried(false) { }`
2. `i[male]` reversed indexing, seriously? Save that for the code 
   obfuscation competitions.
3. Replace magic constants (`100`) with a named constant that 
   describes its meaning.
4. `//( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)` I too like ASCII-art, but that adds nothing
   to the documentation of the code.
5. You have one or two inconsistencies with naming. Most of the code
   used `camelCase` for variables and functions, but you have a `num_trials` variable
   and a `Percentage()` function that break that pattern.

Comment: You mean `camelCase` right? `//( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)`
Thank you.

Comment: Ooops, my bad :P

Comment: @EngieOP, here is the link with the funny drawing, BTW: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: I know what CamelCase is `:)`.  I just didn't care when I was coding this, because I didn't think I was going to show anyone. `:P`

Comment: If you use `std::array`, use `.size()` for the iteration limits. If you use `<random>`, especially a `uniform_int` distribution, you won't need the casts anymore.

Answer (score 8):

- There doesn't seem to be a need for separate `Male` and `Female` structures as they hold the same exact data.  Instead, just have one named `Person` and create `male` and `female` instances of it.

  You also don't need `class`es if you're not going to have any `private` data; just use `struct`s.

  ```
  struct Person
  {
      bool isMarried;
      int salary;

      Person() : isMarried(false) {}
  };
  ```

  ```
  Person males[MALES];
  Person females[FEMALES];
  ```
- Regarding the use of C++11, you can start by removing both `std::srand()` and `std::rand()` and replacing them with functionality from the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) library, particularly [`std::shuffle()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Comment: I used `std::random_shuffle()`

Comment: @EngieOP: I know.  `std::shuffle()` is different (the link shows both of those functions).

Comment: Okay. Had to look closely to see the difference.

Comment: @EngieOP The difference will be more clear in a near future when your compiler will excplicitly tell "this function is deprecated, use `std::shuffle` instead" :)

Answer (score 7):

When you fill `male[]` and `female[]`:

```
//Fill array of Females and Males with random salaries ranging from 1 to 10
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    int output = MIN + (rand() % (int)(MAX - MIN + 1));
    i[male].salary = output; //( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
}
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    int output = MIN + (rand() % (int)(MAX - MIN + 1));
    i[female].salary = output;
}
```

Some issues / strangeness:

- The comment is misleading, should be salaries ranging from MIN to MAX
- Replace the hardcoded 100 in the loop condition with the `MALES` and `FEMALES` you defined
- Why `i[male]` instead of `male[i]` ?
- Why the poorly named `output` variable? Just assign directly

`marriageTest` is doing a bit too much,
it would be better to split the initialization and the dating parts to different functions.

The program outputs "Percentage" that's not actually percentage:

> Percentage: 0.6828

I think you want to multiply this by 100 (and maybe stick a `%` at the end)

Answer (score 2):

- A *No Raw Loops* mantra: calculating `maxMan` and `minWomen` should be factored out in a (possibly templated) function. Same goes for initialization of salaries. The match-finding loop is really `std::find`.
- Shuffling both arrays seems like doing extra work. I don't see how shuffling just `men` and inspecting `women` sequentially would change the result.
- There's no reason for an `isMarried` property: `std::erase` a couple once they are matched (yes you'd need `std::vector`s instead of arrays).

Comment: Actually, since the arrays were randomly generated in the first place, you don't need to shuffle any of them, do you?

Comment: @CompuChip: _That_ I am not sure. Not shuffling at all imposes some correlation. Should you prove me wrong I'd be glad to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Percentage` function could be improved. The first observation is that it is unnecessary to accumulate the *number* of trials, since this is already stored in the std::vector (the postcondition guarantees `trials == results.size()`). Moreover, I would avoid the raw loop here like so:

```
double percentage(const std::vector<double>& results)
{
    return std::accumulate(results.cbegin(), results.cend(), 0.0) / results.size();
}
```

Readability is improved a lot as well. In `marriageTest`, you might as well do `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`. In general, I think it's a good idea *not* to use `push_back` unless you have a specific reason. For more on the topic, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10890653/3475799).